# How to send multiple music files using sockets?

Tags: python, file, sockets, server, client

I am using python 3.6 and ubuntu 18.04.

I am able to send single music file using socket-python (in binary mode) and i want to send multiple music files from server to client.

Problem is, at the receiver end (that is client), all the music files (approx 120 files sent from server) gets collected in one single file making it a 9 hour long single music file.

I have tried using time.sleep method (does not work), tried sending bogus element (error was shown) and tried sending some random character to end the file writing at the client side and initiate new file write (but random character requires encoding and decoding, so again error as binary data was unable to decode).

SERVER CODE

```
import socket
import os
import send_file
import time


s = socket.socket()
host = ""
port = 9997

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print("Binding Done\n")

socket_object, address = s.accept()
print("Connection Established\n")

print("Sending file...")
file_class = send_file.send_files() #ignore
file_names = file_class.files #ignore - contains list of path of music file
socket_object.sendall( str(len(file_names)).encode() )

for i in file_names:
    f = open(i, 'rb')
    buf = f.read(1024)
    while buf:
        socket_object.sendall(buf)
        buf = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

print("Files Send")
socket_object.close()
s.close()
```

CLIENT CODE

```
import socket
import os
import time


def recv_file(i):
    f = open("/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/File_Transfer/B/"+"M"+str(i)+".mp3", 'wb')
    buf = s.recv(1024)
    while buf:
        f.write(buf)
        buf = s.recv(1024)
    f.close()


s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9997
s.connect((host, port))


print("Receiving data...")
l = s.recv(1024).decode() #ignore - length of total number of files i.e., 120 approx
for i in range(int(l)):
    recv_file(i+1)


print("Files Collected")
s.close()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. It is designed for sending streams of data. At TCP level there are no files. It doesn't split streams in any file-oriented chunks.

Look at your code:

```py
for i in file_names:
    f = open(i, 'rb')
    buf = f.read(1024)
    while buf:
        socket_object.sendall(buf)
        buf = f.read(1024)
    f.close()
```

You just glue all files in a single stream, and your client has no idea when one file ends and the next file starts.

The task of sending multiple files over TCP could be solved in many ways:

1. Develop your own protocol. E.g.: first send the number of files, then send an array of 8-byte-encoded file lengths, and then the stream of file contents. The receiving end reads number of files, then parses file lengths. Knowing the lengths the receiver correctly splits the stream into files.
2. Use existing multi-file packaging formats: tar, cpio, zip, etc. Pack files before sending, then send the resulting package. On the receiving end unpack the package after receiving.
3. **Recommended way** Use existing protocols for sending files over TCP: TFTP or FTP.

I'd recommend using TFTP. It is very simple and reasonably efficient. There are several implementations in Python, such as [tftpy](https://pypi.org/project/tftpy/)

On the remote machine where you want to upload your files to, start TFTP server:

```py
import tftpy

server = tftpy.TftpServer('<destination-folder>')
server.listen('0.0.0.0', 54321)
```

On the machine with files start the client:

```py
import tftpy

client = tftpy.TftpClient('your.server.address', 54321)
for name in ("fileA", "fileB", "fileC"):
    # the first argument is the name on the remote machine
    # the second argument is the name on the local machine
    client.upload(name, name)
```